# Alternative to AutoIt that can interact with browser and desktop windows?

Tags: selenium, automation, autoit

I used AutoIT for certain projects where I need to get some info from a text file, then from an Excel file, use it in a web browser, get some info from there, and then use that info in a Oracle project and repeat for n entries. I'm looking for a way to do this with C#, or at least, a better way and found Selenium and Winium, but I can't find enough info about them working together and being able to open Excel and textfiles and such.

Any recommendation on what to use for these scenario? I don't really know much about automation and I'm looking for some guidence in best practices and recommended software.

Comment: Read the text file with `system.io`, read the excel file with something like `https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader` (lots of excel readers available).  But i would also suggest you think about why your data is fragmented in different locations and why it's in its current structure. Point being - find another way to move that data into your automated test. It's best for automated tests to focus tests on their purpose and not mess about with applications that are not related to that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to assess the coverage of automation that you will be doing. Seems like (for me) is a business process automation which RPA can provide. If majority of the automated tasks are not browser related, then selenium is not the best solution for this.

You can check with UiPath, Automation Anywhere, Blueprism etc.

The tools covers not just browser but anything you can see from your screen and can be executed unattended.

You may check this one out, `https://www.uipath.com/rpa/robotic-process-automation`